# Unable to configure CiviCRM on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation

Wordpress 4.2
CiviCRM 4.6

I've reached the point where I am running the CiviCRM Installer. I get nothing but a blank screen

Comment: Please turn on full error logging in PHP to get an error onscreen, or check out your system log. Then edit the question to include the specific errors that are occurring and we'll try to help you further. Without an error, there isn't much to go on.

Comment: This is a shared hosting service and I am new at it. It may take me a while to find the way to do this in cPanel.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the hosting service has PHP 5.2.17 installed and this version of CiviCRM requires 5.3

Comment: Time to get a new host!